# Using string to call function

Tags: python, python-2.7, nodebox-linguistics

```
from en import verb
print verb.tenses()
print verb.infinitive('argue')


['infinitive', 'present participle', 'past plural', '2nd singular present', '2nd singular past', 'past', '3rd singular present', 'past participle', '1st singular present', '1st singular past', '3rd singular past', 'present plural']
    argue
```

[Using this](https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics).

I can't find a method that give all tenses of the verb. There is only one way to call each function: replace space from the list using verb object. How can I accomplish this?

The input: `argue`. Output should be: `arguing`,`argued`,`argue`..

Comment: Do you want to conjugate the verb? If so have you seen the documentation [here](https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics#verb_conjugation)?

Comment: I want all forms of the verb. I went through the source code and couldn't a function that does the trick. The documentation doesn't mention a function like this. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that fails?

Comment: I have to call `verb.infinitive(),verb.present_ participle...`. I am looking for a shorthand to do this looping the list strings.

Comment: Can you provide sample input and it's corresponding output? Your code sample is unclear.

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford The input: `argue` . Output: `arguing`,`argued`,`argue`..

Comment: Please refer to http://www.sscce.org Your code doesn't compile. Are you intending to run it in a shell? Also, 'output' means both 'expected' and 'actual' output.

Comment: Will you have to download this package https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics. It seems to work. Please check again. The actual output implies calling each of the nine functions. I am looking for better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of names / parameters for each name of the tense. For example:

```
tense_functions = {
    'infinitive': ('infinitive', {}),
    'present participle': ('present_participle', {}),
    '1st singular present': ('present', {'person': 1}),
    ...
}
for tense in verb.tenses():
    options = tense_functions[tense]
    func = getattr(verb, options[0])
    print(func('argue', **options[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks! I am fairly new to python. Please explain more, I can't seem understand much. 
`

Comment: You can't do this, because the list would have to contain `2nd_singular_present` and you can't have function names starting with numbers. (well, you can, but not easily and I doubt your library exposes them)

Comment: Yes, I just figured it out. So remove it from the comment. Sorry, my bad. Please explain the code more.

Comment: I get this error: `NameError: name 'person' is not defined`

Comment: Missed quotes - fixed now.

Comment: I understand your approach, which works great. But please explain these lines `func = getattr(verb, options[0]) print(func('argue', **options[1]))`. How did you create a callable here?

Comment: `**options[1]` is used how here?

Comment: `**options[1]` is expanded to the keyword arguments for the function. Since some of the tenses require the `person` or other arguments and others don't, a dictionary can be used instead. Basically `f(name=value)` is the same as `f(**{'name': value})`. Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Answer (score 0):

You can do `getattr(verb, 'infinitive')` and it will return a reference the the exact same function as `verb.infinitive`.  You can then loop through a list of strings like this:

```
some_tenses = ['infinitive', 'present_participle', 'past_plural',]
for tense in some_tenses:
    print getattr(verb, tense)('argue')
```

Of course, the strings would have to be the exact function names in the module, whatever they are.

You might also want to look into `hasattr()`.  If you try `getattr()` but the attribute you provide doesn't exist for that object, you'll get an AttributeError.  Using `if hasattr(...` before you try `getattr(...` will let you handle such cases gracefully.  Alternatively, you can use a try...except block.